# Sinatra and custom pretty errors in production on ubuntu

Tags: error-handling, sinatra, rack, production-environment

I'm tearing my hair out.  On my mac, custom pretty errors are shown that I want to display to my users. When I deploy to my ubuntu box I get a minimal black and white error message instead.

I've got sinatra error handling, like so

```
set :raise_errors, false
set :show_exceptions, false

not_found do
    erb :'errors/not_found'
end
```

I assumed it was because I was running nginx and thin (on ubuntu) but if I bypass this stack and run direct I still have the problem on ubuntu.

```
ruby start.rb #I get a minimal black and white error
```

OR

```
rackup -E production config.ru  #I get a minimal black and white error
```

OR

```
rackup -E development config.ru  #I get rack stack trace
```

I get pretty error on my mac, regardless of how I start and even if I use Rack::ShowExceptions.  I'm running ruby 1.9.2 and sinatra 1.3.2.

Any clues as to how I can get pretty errors to users in production?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after several failed attempts to fix this over several weeks, I realised I was doing something stupid.  I was missing [email_errors][to] in my production config.yaml.  This was breaking my error_handler.  Had I read the rack stack trace when I added 'use Rack::ShowExceptions' to my config.ru, I would have seen the problem, except I didn't read it because the error_handler was throwing the same error I was expecting from my test error.  Stupid oversight.